# Quando usar onCreateView() vs onActivityCreated()?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Queria saber as questões abaixo:

-Quando utilizar o onCreateView() vs onActivityCreated()?

-Quais desses dois métodos devo usar para preencher um listView com adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O **onCreateView()** é utilizado quando vc deseja criar um **Fragment** personalizado. Cuidado, caso vc use ele para criar uma view pois, mais tarde, vc precisa destruir esse objeto chamando o **onDestroyView()**. Ele é sempre executado antes do **onActivityCreated()**.

O **onActivityCreated()** é chamado após o anterior informando que uma Fragment View foi instanciada.

Sobre qual usar para preencher um ListView, use o **onCreateView()** pois o **onActivityCreated()** é mais para recuperar o estado de objetos já criado.

**Essa última descrição não testei!**

Comment: Cuidado, o método `onDestroyView` não é pra ser chamado. Ele ja é chamado pelo `FragmentManager` durante a destruição da`View` conforme o ciclo de vida do `Fragment`.